# C++ code Working on window gcc, but not working on linux gcc

Tags: c++

I use dev-c++ for coding and use TDM-gcc-4.9-2

hi I do my homework and done to make.
and I submit it to linux auto scoring site.
but it did not work.

So I tested in linux with geany and g++ 7.3.0

I use Global variable a lot.
and it might seem 'rank' variable is problem.

Do you explain what's wrong on this code?
thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int **data, **rank, **sorted, **superb;
int N, K, T;    //student, subject, standard_subject
int memory = 50;

void inputdata(){
    ifstream in("5.inp");
    if( in.is_open() ){
        in>>N>>K>>T;
        data = new int*[N];
        for(int x = 0; x<N; x++){
            data[x] = new int[K+1];
        }
        rank = new int*[N];
        for(int x = 0; x<N; x++){
            rank[x] = new int[K+1];
            for(int y=0; y<K+1; y++){
                rank[x][y] = 1;
            }
        }
        sorted = new int*[N];
        for(int x = 0; x<N; x++){
            sorted[x] = new int[K+1];
        }
        superb = new int*[N];
        for(int x = 0; x<N; x++){
            superb[x] = new int[K+1];
        }

        //data inputing
        cout<<"N is "<<N<<" K is "<<K<<" T is "<<T<<endl;
        for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<K+1; j++){
                in>>data[i][j];
                //cout<<"i is "<<i<<" j is "<<j<<"  "<<data[i][j]<<" ";
            }
            //cout<<endl;
        }
        for(int x = 0; x < N; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y<K+1;y++){
                cout<<data[x][y]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
    else
        cout<<"input error"<<endl;
}

void ranking(){
    for(int x = 0; x<N;x++)
        rank[x][0] = data[x][0]; //ID
        cout<<K<<endl;
        for(int j = 1; j<K+1; j++){
        for(int i= 0; i<N; i++){
            for(int x= 0; x<N; x++){
                if(x==i)    continue;
                //cout<<"i is "<<i<<" j is "<<j<<" data i is "<<data[i][j]<<" x is "<<x<<" data x is "<<data[x][j]<<endl; 
                if(data[i][j]<data[x][j]){
                    rank[i][j] += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        }
}

void sortedByT(){
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<K+1; j++){
            sorted[rank[i][T]-1][j] = rank[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void swap(int **arr, int index1, int index2){
    int temp;
    for(int j=0; j<K+1; j++){
        temp = arr[index1][j];
            arr[index1][j] = arr[index2][j];
        arr[index2][j] = temp;
    }
}

    int takeSuperb(){
    int numOfSuperb = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
        int ranker = 0;
        for(int j = 1; j<K+1; j++){
                if(rank[i][j]<4)
                ranker += 1;
            if(ranker>=4){
                for(int x=0; x<K+1; x++)
                    superb[numOfSuperb][x] = rank[i][x];
                    numOfSuperb += 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
        for(int x = 0; x<numOfSuperb; x++) //buble sort
        for(int y = x+1; y<numOfSuperb; y++)
            if(superb[x][0]>superb[y][0])
                swap(superb, x, y);
    return numOfSuperb;
    }

int combination(int n, int r){
    if(n==0||r==0) return 1;
    else return combination(n-1, r-1) + combination(n-1,r);
    }

//int *combiArr = new int[combination(N,2)][2];
int combiArr[2], Cresult=0;
void combiSearcher(int *arr, int index, int n, int r, int target){
        if(r==0){
        bool s1win2 = false, s2win10 = false, s2win2 = false, s1win10 = 
false;
        for(int j = 1; j<K+1; j++){
            if(rank[combiArr[0]][j]+2 < rank[combiArr[1]][j])   s1win2 = 
    true;
            if(rank[combiArr[0]][j] > rank[combiArr[1]][j]+10)  s2win10 = 
true;
            if(rank[combiArr[0]][j] > rank[combiArr[1]][j]+2)   s2win2 = 
true;
                if(rank[combiArr[0]][j]+10 < rank[combiArr[1]][j])  s1win10 
= true;
            if( (s1win2&&s2win10) || (s2win2&&s1win10) ){
                Cresult += 1;
                //cout<<combiArr[0]+1<<" , "<<combiArr[1]+1<<endl;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if(target == n) return;
    else{
        arr[index] = target;
        combiSearcher(arr, index+1, n, r-1, target+1);
        combiSearcher(arr, index, n, r, target+1);
    }
}

int main(){
    inputdata();
    ranking();
    sortedByT();
    cout<<"sorted by T"<<endl<<N<<endl;
    for(int x = 0; x < N; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y<K+1;y++){
            cout<<sorted[x][y]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    int result = takeSuperb();
    cout<<"superb"<<endl<<result<<endl;
    if(result>0){
        for(int i = 0; i<result; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<=K;j++){
                cout<<superb[i][j]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }

    if(N>10){
        combiSearcher(combiArr, 0, N, 2, 0);
    }
    else{
        Cresult = 0;
    }
    cout<<Cresult<<endl;
```

Comment: This is what happens when one uses `using namespace std;`.

Comment: _and it might seem 'rank' variable is problem._ Did you get a compiler complaint? If so, you should copy/paste it into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++11 there is a struct `std::rank` in the standard library. Because you are using `using namespace std;` your definition of `rank` clashes with it.

If you are compiling on gcc 4.9 without extra compiler flags, then C++03 will be the default used and this problem does not occur.

For newer gcc versions however C++11 (or later) is the default and the problem occurs.

This is not an isolated case either. For example with C++17, `data` would have the same problem.

Another example in your code is `swap`, which is also defined in the standard library but wont immediately give you a compiler error, because your definition will be considered an overload of `std::swap` which always takes two parameters.

This is exactly why one shouldn't use `using namespace std;` and instead always qualify things used from it with `std::`.

Answer (score 0):

`rank` is reserved(keyword) in the `std`
Ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank

Try using another word as a variable name instead.

Comment: Or, may be, better: "Stop to use `using namespace std;`" to prevent exactly such accidents.